# Why does bash wildcard * not work in a buildah run command?

Tags: centos, redhat, redhat-containers, buildah

While attempting to build an image via Buildah from CentOS:latest, yum wouldn't complete commands due to "no URLs in mirrorlist," so I added the following to the Dockerfile

```
RUN sed -i -e "s;mirrorlist=;#mirrorlist=;g" -e "s;#baseurl=http://mirror;baseurl=http://vault;g" /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux*
```

which worked flawlessly.

Afterwards, while experimenting with running the same command in a container directly, the following error was presented:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-32-232 buildah]$ buildah run centos-working-container sed -i -e "s;mirrorlist=;#mirrorlist=;g" -e "s;#baseurl=http://mirror;baseurl=http://vault;g" /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux*
/usr/bin/sed: can't read /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux*: No such file or directory
Error: while running runtime: exit status 2
```

This forced me to run the command manually across CentOS-Linux-Appstream.repo, CentOS-Linux-BaseOS.repo, etc

1. Tripled checked spelling and directly copied exact command from Dockerfile.
2. Tested the command on local CentOS VM (it worked normally).